# Add css file to Symfony App using Webpack Encore

Tags: css, symfony, webpack, webpack-encore

I'm installing a theme that I purchased from getbootsrap.com into my Symfony 4 web application. I copied over the css files into assets/css, and added them as entries to my webpack.config.js, however I am getting the following error message:

```
yarn run encore dev
yarn run v1.7.0
$ /home/vagrant/code/node_modules/.bin/encore dev
Running webpack ...

ERROR  Failed to compile with 9 errors                                                                                                                                                                     
12:40:57

These relative modules were not found:

* ../fonts/entypo.eot?79395234 in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--1-2!./assets/css/entypo.css
* ../fonts/entypo.svg?79395234 in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--1-2!./assets/css/entypo.css
* ../fonts/entypo.ttf?79395234 in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--1-2!./assets/css/entypo.css
* ../fonts/entypo.woff2?79395234 in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--1-2!./assets/css/entypo.css
* ../fonts/entypo.woff?79395234 in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--1-2!./assets/css/entypo.css
* ../fonts/socicon.eot?a93r5t in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--1-2!./assets/css/socicon.css
* ../fonts/socicon.svg?a93r5t in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--1-2!./assets/css/socicon.css
* ../fonts/socicon.ttf?a93r5t in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--1-2!./assets/css/socicon.css
* ../fonts/socicon.woff?a93r5t in ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--1-2!./assets/css/socicon.css

error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Here is my webpack.config.js entry:

```
.addStyleEntry('css/app', [
    './node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    './assets/css/theme.css',
    './assets/css/entypo.css',
    './assets/css/socicon.css',
])
```

Comment: Check this out - https://chriscourses.com/blog/loading-fonts-webpack